# Does pwelch function, in matlab, adopt already the correction factor due to the window?

Tags: power-spectral-density

Does  pwelch  function, in matlab, adopt already the correction factor due to the window?
When we use a window, like hamming or hanning, a [correction factor](https://community.sw.siemens.com/s/article/window-correction-factors) for the amplitude or energy is needed. In my case the energy correction factor is needed. Is it possible that pwelch does already a correction, or should I use a correction due to my window type. Does the overlap affect the energy?
I've seen that I am not the only one to ask this question like here, but nobody answered.
Thanks

P.S.
If you look at the code below you can see that, without setting no option
a and b are equal, while c which has a different scaling setting is different

```
x = 0:.0001:1
y = cos(2500*x)+cos(1800*x)+cos(700*x)+cos(250*x);   % case 1

plot(x,y)
[z w] = pwelch(y);
[z1 w1] = pwelch(y,'power');


semilogy(w,z,'o-')
xlim([0 1])
a=trapz(w,z)
b=trapz(x,y.^2)
c=trapz(w1,z1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be an optional parameter, 'spectrumtype', see below.

[image]

https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pwelch.html

Comment: Hi, I did a try with the code. But the results are not consistent. If I do not set the spectrum type the result seems to be equal. If I set 'power' the result is different. I would have expected the reverse

Comment: That's consistent with the documentation: "Omitting the spectrumtype, or specifying 'psd', returns the power spectral density. Specifying 'power' scales each estimate of the PSD by the equivalent noise bandwidth of the window".

Comment: If I didn't specifiy anything, I obtain the PSD with its integral equal to the mean of the variable y.^2 . So I suppose that if it is equal there is a scaling to correct the lost energy due to the window. Instead the part of the user guide that you are citing says that the scaling is in the 'power' option. What am I missing?